# Load an SVG image externally and style it with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fairly large svg image that I would like to load from an external file and then style with css. If I just cut and paste the code inline it works fine, but the huge html file is almost unreadable.
I have searched online and I have found a suggestion but I cannot get it to work.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Chess</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
      <object id="inline-1"
              data="svg/BasicBoard.svg"
              type="image/svg+xml">
      </object>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            var svg = document.getElementById('inline-1');
            console.log(svg);
      </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I checked the source and everything seems to be there, but I just get a "black" box (no css).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

do you have this attribute `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` in your SVG file?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
...
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, I have that